# From an engineering standpoint, what is the purpose of the indent in a coffee lid?

Tags: design, applied-mechanics

I've see the same lids every day but I never really thought about their construction. There is an indent in a "Solo Travel Lid" for coffee cups that is just above the hole that you drink the coffee from.

[image]

You can see the crescent shaped indent in the image. What is it for? Does it somehow increase fluid flow? Is it just a good spot for your upper lip? If so, why is there not a matching one for the nose? I tried googling this but I got no answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the "Solo Traveler" [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US4589569):

> A more specific object of the present invention is to provide a lid having an opening formed therethrough to enable drinking, and having a recess formed in the lid adjacent the opening to accommodate the upper lip of one drinking from the cup

This is also illustrated in the patent diagrams.
[image: Patent Image]

I came across this [interesting article](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/05/the-rise-of-the-plastic-disposable-coffee-cup-lid/238573/) on the history, use, design, and styles of disposable lids.  The Solo Traveler is prominently featured for its excellent aesthetics and design .  The article reiterates that:

> the Solo Traveler lid was designed to accommodate the nose and lip of a drinker. In accomplishing this design goal, the necessary height of the lid made it useful for foam-topped gourmet coffees.

Additionally, when upright, the recess acts as a reservoir (complete with drainhole) to catch drips/spills/splashes that might otherwise run down the cup and create the infamous coffee stain ring.

Comment: Great response! That mouth is super creepy looking though

Comment: Based on all the patent drawings I have seen, I think there is some weird requirement that engineers _must_ draw everything and are strictly forbidden from getting an artist to help.

Comment: lol creepy mouth. maybe i just have an extra large nose... :>)

Comment: Wait... the person who filed the patent thinks that that hole is for *directly drinking from*, and not sticking a coffee straw into?  Weird!

Comment: Gotta love how there are at least fifty numbered items in the drawings. I could never come up with more than two. 1 - cup, 2 - lid.

Comment: @MrLister Those numbers aren't individual items, but specific features being referenced in the claims section. And the main reason there are so many is that all patents are intentionally over-complex and simultaneously cryptically vague.

Comment: yeah, the problem with drinking directly is that the air holes are to small to give good flow so you actually have to suck on it a little